# How to delete entity link in Dynamics CRM 4 using webservices

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

If I have a 1:N relationship with A with B.  Is there a web service method that I could use to remove the link between A and B[i] with out actually removing the entity B[i], if the Id of both are know.  Btw A and B are custom entities. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Set the `IsNull` and `IsNullSpecified` properties of the respective lookup attribute in B[i] to true and update the record. The A record does not "know" about the link anyway.